How to match xticks text and label order
I have some mismatch between the order of the x label in my plot and the text I am adding, using seaborn boxplot with python.
a4_dims = (3.5, 4)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)

plot = sns.boxplot(data= Encaps_data_2E, x='Shape_Diameter', y='Concentration (mg/ml)', hue='Shape', 
            order = ['Y0.6', 'Z0.6', 'Spi0.6'],
            orient = 'v', 
            dodge=False,
            showmeans=True, meanprops={"marker":"o","markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black","markersize":"10"})

plot.legend([],[], frameon=False)

means = Encaps_data_2E.groupby(['Shape_Diameter'])['Concentration (mg/ml)'].mean()
stdevs = Encaps_data_2E.groupby(['Shape_Diameter'])['Concentration (mg/ml)'].std()
count = Encaps_data_2E.groupby(['Shape_Diameter'])['Concentration (mg/ml)'].count()

for xtick in plot.get_xticks():
    plot.text(xtick,means[xtick] + 0.034,str(round(means[xtick],3))+"", 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='small',color='00000',weight='semibold')
    plot.text(xtick,means[xtick] + 0.027, str(round(stdevs[xtick]/means[xtick]*100))+"% CV", 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='small',color='00000',weight='semibold')
    plot.text(xtick,means[xtick] + 0.02, "n= "+ str(round(count[xtick],0)), 
            horizontalalignment='center',size='small',color='00000',weight='light', style = 'italic')
    
ax.set(ylabel="Total concentration (mg/mL)")
ax.set(xlabel="")

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=0.15)
ax.figure.savefig('Fig2E_Conc.png', dpi = 300, bbox_inches = 'tight')

I ensured that that the order was correct from the dataframe but it seems that the groupby is taking over the order. Any idea on how to force the order of the text?
